# Make input fields green when all in one row are filled

Tags: jquery, json

I created this check that should check whether the `syllables` are matched with the `syllables` in my JSON, I (kind of) successfully did so, but is it possible to change the input fields to green `btn btn-success` buttons when all the `syllables` of a certain row are filled out? 
EDIT: a `row` is the bootstrap class `row`. The template is pretty much only bootstrap.

This is how my JSON looks like;

```
 {
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "testforcounter",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "testforcounter",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "Texel",
      "syllables": [
        "tex",
        "el",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "3",
      "syllables": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}
```

as you can see the first word contains 2 `syllables`, when the user fills both the input fields out in the front-end it should mark them green when BOTH are correct. for example: the `word` 3 has 3 input fields because it contains 3 `syllables` in my JSON file. When the user fills out in the 3 input fields 1,2,3 it should mark all the 3 green at the same time. NOT when the user fills out 1 and then it pops to green, 2 and that input field pops green, 3 the third input field pops to green. They all should remain input fields untill all the desired input fields are filled out correctly and THEN they all should jump to green.

This is how my function looks like:

```
function prepareCheck() {
$.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
   $(document).on('change', '.syl-input', function() {
       var rowCounter = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
       var inputCounter = $(this).attr('id');
       var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables[inputCounter];
       var jsylall = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables;
       var valueInput = $(this).val();

       console.log(jsyl);

       if (valueInput == jsyl) {
        var value = valueInput;
          var correctBtn = $('<button/>', {
             'class': 'btn btn-success buttonCorrect',
             'type': 'button'
          });
            S.addRight();
            $(this).replaceWith(correctBtn);
            $('.buttonCorrect').html(value);
            value = '';
       } else if ($.inArray(valueInput, jsylall) >= -1) {
            S.addWrong();
       }
  });
});
}
```

a picture for you to visualize it:

[image]

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and produce a [mcve]

Comment: Please post HTML markup

Comment: Even tho the HTML markup won't add anything really to it? The input fields are made by jquery/javascript

Comment: @JJShaw - it would give us information such as "what is a row"? Table row or aligned spans in a div?

Comment: Good note @mplungjan.  i'll make the edit

Comment: I updated my answer. I do not know the structure of a bootstrap row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange:

```
function prepareCheck() {
  $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
     $(document).on('change', '.syl-input', function() {
```

I would code

```
$(document).on('change', '.syl-input', function() {.....});
```

and

```
function prepareCheck() {
  $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {...})`
```

For the check, try something like this

```
var $row = $(this).closest(".row"), // assuming the "row" has class="row"
    $buts = $row.find(".syl-input"), 
    $correct = $row.find(".buttonCorrect");
$buts.toggleClass("green",$buts.length==$correct.length);
```

Comment: I tried making a fiddle as much as I could (basically pasted all the desired code you most likely are looking for) into the fiddle. However I cannot seem to paste any JSON into it.  https://jsfiddle.net/StackOverflowAccount/sa2eowhh/108/

Comment: Where are you calling createExercise(json) ?

Comment: Also you add the event handler in the prepare. Don't.